# UIView Custom delegate not call when click on button

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, delegates, swift3

I have a view controller that has one button. When I click on that button, I want to add my custom view(xib) as a subview to the view controller. In my custom view(xib), I also have a custom delegate and one button. But when I click the button in my custom view(xib), the delegate method in the view controller is never called.

```
//View Controller
class BusinessMainViewController: UIViewController,BusinessSettingViewDelegate {
//MARK: - business setting view delegate
func businessSettingViewAction(settingView: BusinessSettingView, button: UIButton) {
    switch button.tag {
    case 100:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    settingView.removeFromSuperview()
}

//MARK: - Button action

@IBAction func settingAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let settingView = BusinessSettingView.init(parentView: self.view)
    settingView.delegate = self
    settingView.showSetting()

} 
}
```

//Custom view + xib:

```
+ xib name : BusinessSettingView.xib
+ custom view class: BusinessSettingView.swift

protocol BusinessSettingViewDelegate {
func businessSettingViewAction (settingView : BusinessSettingView, button : UIButton)
}

class BusinessSettingView: UIView {

var parentView : UIView!
var delegate : BusinessSettingViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

convenience init(parentView : UIView) {
    self.init(frame: parentView.frame)

    let view : UIView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BusinessSettingView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView
    view.frame = self.frame
    view.alpha = 1
    self.addSubview(view)

    self.parentView = parentView
}

func showSetting() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.parentView.addSubview(self)
    }
}

//MARK: - button action

@IBAction func historyAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.businessSettingViewAction(settingView: self, button: sender)
    }
}
}


// self.delegate is always nil
```

Comment: Make sure that the subview is sized correctly, otherwise you can't interact with it

Comment: @MadProgrammer the size is correct. I want my subview size the same as my view controller size.

Comment: Sorry, missed the constructor :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you write the IBACtion on which you are handling button click event.

Comment: @NikunjDamani : this action, IBAction func historyAction(_ sender: UIButton){}.

Comment: can you please this add IBAction in your provided code so i can check it.

Comment: @NikunjDamani : I already added it. It is under the //MARK: - button action.

Comment: have you added the breakpoint at historyAction it's being called or not on button click.

Comment: @NikunjDamani: yes it is. But delegate is always nil.

Comment: here your code is messed why you are adding view in parent view from that view you should add the view from parent view using addSubview

Comment: because of that your parent view might become nil with ARC